# having trouble with this c quick sort while using an array struct

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct

The program doesn't crash, the build is successful, and it runs through the rest of main properly. The only problem is that the sort doesn't actually sort the array.

I left out the creation of the array and the rest of `main` simply because I've already tested them with another sort, and they work properly. However I'm supposed to use a higher level sort so I have to change things.

```
//struct for the array
typedef double darray_value_t;

typedef struct darray_t_tag {
    darray_value_t *data;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} darray_t;

//top of main
quickSort(&dataset, 0, dataset.size - 1);
//rest of main

//functions used to for the quick sort
void quickSort(darray_t *dataset, int lowValue, int highValue) {
    if (lowValue < highValue) {
        int part = partition(dataset, lowValue, highValue);

        quickSort(dataset, lowValue, part - 1);

        quickSort(dataset, part + 1, highValue);
    }
}

darray_value_t partition(darray_t *dataset, int lowValue, int highValue) {
    int pivot = dataset->data[highValue];

    int i = (lowValue - 1);

    for (int j = lowValue; j < highValue; j++) {
        if (dataset->data[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swapValues(&dataset->data[i], &dataset->data[j]);
        }
    }

    swapValues(&dataset->data[i + 1], &dataset->data[highValue]);

    return (i + 1);
}

void swapValues(darray_value_t *a, darray_value_t *b) {
    darray_value_t temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: `int pivot = dataset->data[highValue]` doesn't do what you probably think it does. Do you get any warning on this line?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the return value of `partition` should be `int`, not `darray_value_t`,
- conversely, the type of `pivot` should be `darray_value_t`, not `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//struct for the array
typedef double darray_value_t;

typedef struct darray_t_tag {
    darray_value_t *data;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
} darray_t;

void swapValues(darray_value_t *a, darray_value_t *b) {
    darray_value_t temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(darray_t *dataset, int lowValue, int highValue) {
    darray_value_t pivot = dataset->data[highValue];
    int i = lowValue;

    for (int j = lowValue; j < highValue; j++) {
        if (dataset->data[j] <= pivot) {
            swapValues(&dataset->data[i++], &dataset->data[j]);
        }
    }
    swapValues(&dataset->data[i], &dataset->data[highValue]);

    return i;
}

//functions used to for the quick sort
void quickSort(darray_t *dataset, int lowValue, int highValue) {
    if (lowValue < highValue) {
        int part = partition(dataset, lowValue, highValue);

        quickSort(dataset, lowValue, part - 1);
        quickSort(dataset, part + 1, highValue);
    }
}

int main() {
    darray_value_t arr[] = { 2.0, 1.5, 4.5, -1 };
    darray_t dataset = { arr, 4, 4 };

    quickSort(&dataset, 0, dataset.size - 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataset.size; i++) {
        printf(" %g", dataset.data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, unfortunately the fixes provided didn't fix the problem. the array is still in the same order as it was when entered, and nothing is changed. i'm honestly not sure where the problem could be then, I print out the array's contents both before and after the sort, and since they're the same it has to be a problem withing the sort.

Comment: @ctrldChaos: without a minimal compilable example, it is difficult to investigate your problem.